# Method won't return array, just one element

Tags: php, class, oop

hi it just wount return all the pic I had this problem before and I don't  realy know what keeps causing it whenever i put my code in class files

```
<?php
class get_pic{

function thumb($id){
$piclist = '';
     if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
    // Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product 
    // details, if no then exit this script and give message why
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productpic WHERE id='$id' ");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                 $path1 = $row["path1"];
                 $piclist ='<li id="thumb"><img id="thumb" style=" position:relative; border:#666 1px solid;  "  src="'.$path1.'" alt="' . $id . '" width="120" height="160" border="1" /></li>';
              } 

          }     

         }
          return $piclist;
       }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: `$piclist` isn't an array?

Comment: I tried to put an array() but then I get just the last pic

Answer (score 0):

Your `$piclist` has only the last value. You should concatenate strings.

Make the following changes:

```
...
if ($productCount > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $piclist .= '<li>...';
```

Comment: @Josh, he did not write this in his question. It is just your assumption.

Comment: @Josh But in HTML list is `<ol>` or `<ul>`. He generates strings with `<li>`. It may be that he needs an array of HTML `<li>` strings. But it is strange. More logical would be to generate a HTML string and output it. Because of that I do not agree with your advices and changing of title. I think that you should rollback your changes, even though this is true that his wording is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this:

```
$piclist = '';
...
$piclist ='<li id="thumb"><img id="thumb" style=" position:relative; border:#666 1px solid;  "  src="'.$path1.'" alt="' . $id . '" width="120" height="160" border="1" /></li>';
```

...to this might fix it:

```
$piclist = array();
...
$piclist[] ='<li id="thumb"><img id="thumb" style=" position:relative; border:#666 1px solid;  "  src="'.$path1.'" alt="' . $id . '" width="120" height="160" border="1" /></li>';
```